# How to convert nested JSON to CSV?

Tags: python, json, csv

I  am  reading a JSON list using WooCommerce's API, and wanting to convert it to a CSV file. How do I achieve that as the input is a nested JSON using pandas? Here is my code:

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from woocommerce import API
wcapi = API(
url = "URL",
consumer_key  = "#######",
consumer_secret = "#########",
wp_api = True,
version = "wc/v3",
verify_ssl = False,
timeout=10
)
r = wcapi.get("orders?per_page=100").json()
print(r)
```

Comment: There should be DictReader in the csv module check it out

Comment: But isn't DictReader useful for converting CSV to JSON? I want to convert JSON to CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you format your data as a dict and use the csv module to convert to csv. Here is an example using your code:

```
import csv

dict = wcapi.get("orders?per_page=100").json()
keys = dict[0].keys()
with open('file_name.csv', 'wb') as output_file:
  dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
  dict_writer.writeheader()
  dict_writer.writerows(dict)
```

Here are the csv [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) which give you all the options in detail.

EDIT: This solution uses csv instead of pandas.

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Instead of using ```df = wcapi.get("orders").text()```. I am using ```df = wcapi.get("orders").text```

Comment: But,  I have a problem, the fields inside the json string are itself a json string, so I am not able to take split out every field into a column header from the nested json.

Comment: Hey I edited my solution to use a dictionary instead of json to avoid the nested json issue. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I was actually trying to use dictionary as well. But now I am getting ```TyperError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'````

Comment: I was able to fix the error - ```with open (r'C:\Users\sprakash\Desktop\test.csv','w') as output_file:```

Comment: But I still have the nested issue where one row has all the meta data - [{'id': 1435, 'name': '1.00 GAL Annual Zinnia Mix  Planter- 1 plant', 'product_id': 1945, 'variation_id': 0, 'quantity': 2, 'tax_class': '', 'subtotal': '19.96', 'subtotal_tax': '1.65', 'total': '19.96', 'total_tax': '1.65', 'taxes': [{'id': 1, 'total': '1.65', 'subtotal': '1.65'}]

Comment: I see the issue is some of the fields in the "dict" object are also objects or arrays. I think to convert to csv you need all the fields to be strings. You have to think about how you want to handle this issue. For example, you could loop throught all the keys in dict and remove the non-string fields. Another thing you could do is replace them with a value like an id.